# Is there a kind of '/dev/null' to fake output file path?

Tags: devices, io

Lets say that I have a CLI which transforms a **file_a** into a **file_b** like so:

```bsh
transform --input /path/to/file_a --ouptut /path/to/file_b
```

I have developed a program that use this CLI and need to unit test it when the CLI is executed. But I don't want my tests to deals with disk writing operation.

Does a fake drive exist on Linux where I can write useless files with no persistence?

Comment: you can use /tmp.

Comment: have you tries wrting to /dev/null ?

Comment: maybe related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/how-can-i-create-a-dev-null-like-blackhole-directory

Answer (score 2):

Even better than `/tmp` are the `tmpfs` volumes. These behave like real filesystems but are actually "RAM drives". They offer :

- read, write and delete is really fast
- purged at power off and unmount

Distributions (at least Debian does it) usually set up one (or more) for you. List them with :

```
mount | grep tmpfs
```

Or :

```
df -h | grep tmpfs
```

which also shows the available space. `/dev/shm` is my favorite candidate.

**EDIT :**

as said in a comment :

> writing to tmpfs files will still fill up your memory and swap.

Which is totally right. The `tmpfs` volumes, like all other volumes, are not a kind of "magical" area where you can store data without limits. They have a defined size (which is reported by the `df ...` command above) and filling them up may end up slowing your computer (I say "may" rather than "will" because I've actually never experienced this : never had to write more than a few MB of disposable data).

Comment: writing to tmpfs files will still fill up your memory and swap.