# How can I redirect process file write operations to /dev/null?

Tags: linux, docker, fuse

I've got a program that generates a crazy amount of data and I'm really only interested in seeing the stdout it generates. Rather than running the program, filling up my disk, then deleting the unwanted files every time, is there a way I could just redirect all that file I/O to /dev/null in the same way I can redirect stdout to /dev/null?

Comment: You mean you want to redirect standard error? What is this "file I/O" you mention?

Comment: It sounds like you're getting unwanted files created. If this is the case and the file names are known beforehand, can you use symbolic links to point the files to `/dev/null`? You'll still have a lot of filenames but the data use is minimal.

Comment: also, what (in GB) is "a crazy amount of data"? How much RAM do you have, in comparison?

Comment: This question is already asked and answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/how-can-i-create-a-dev-null-like-blackhole-directory

Comment: The application is a non-traditional compiler that I work on. In practice about 10-20TB of data. nullfs might be an option, I'll play with it. I'm wondering if Docker can be useful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a /dev/null-like "blackhole" directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/how-can-i-create-a-dev-null-like-blackhole-directory)